# Processing Batch files coming every 2 minutes in system using spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to process my near real time batch csv files using spark streaming. I am reading these files in batches of 100 files and doing some operation and writing to output files. I am using `spark.readstream` and `spark.writestream` functions to read and write streaming files.

I am trying to find out how I can stop the spark streaming?

```
stream_df = spark.readstream.csv(filepath_directory). 
        .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 10)

query = spark.writeStream.format("parquet")..outputMode("append").option("output filepath")
```

I faced the issue while streaming job is running, due to some reason
my job is failing or some exceptions are.

I tried `try`, `except`. 
I am planning to stop the query in case of any exceptions and process the same code again.

I used `query.stop()`, is this the right way to stop streaming job?

I read one post, I am not sure whether it is for `Dstream` and how to execute this code in my pyspark code.

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-shutdown-spark-streaming-job-gracefully-lan-jiang

Comment: Please post your full code.

Comment: I am trying to add the code :